# openTip javascript hide by closeButton AND timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, opentip

I am creating a tooltip for comments that should only show momentarily for a few seconds. But it never disappears no matter what options I pick. The openTip documentation is very unclear about how to make a tooltip disappear-by-seconds and lacks examples.

```
<textarea class="textareaclass" id="body" name="body" placeholder="Comment" data-ot="Spamming is restricted. Comments are subject to US law." data-ot-delay="0.1" data-ot-hide-trigger="closeButton" data-ot-style="alert" data-ot-hidedelay="1.2" data-ot-fixed="true"></textarea>
```

How do I make it so that the tooltip disappears within 2 seconds and also when there is a click on "X" close button.

No matter what I try, tooltip seems to stay forever. "hidedelay" doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've given a quick look at the docs and couldn't find a plugin's solution for this. The "hideDelay" option refers to the delay after clicking the close button, and not after opening the tooltip.

What about a timeout? You can set the timeout you want and, at the end, you close the tooltip manually. Like this (with 2 seconds):

```
$('textarea').on('mouseenter', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.ot-close').trigger('click');
    }, 2000);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nxp1Lccm/

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I thought it would be strange if that option didn't exist in openTip already.

Comment: I think you can suggest that option for the authors, because I wasn't able to find anything related. Personally, I'd use the `setTimeout` for this. :)